# Best Practice Restructuring UserObject using Spring Security/MVC 3.1

Tags: spring-security, implementation

Before Spring Security/MVC, I had a simple relatively insecure userobject stored in my sessions that held a lot of data and that I'd update in my service logic and then store back in session with every modification.

Now I've successfully locked down my userobject as a Principal object with the same complex data structure.  As before the userObject is available to the view after authentication with it's initial state stored in it, but it seems my userObject implementing UserDetails is now not changeable (without creating a new Authentication Object on each request).  It certainly cannot just be stashed back into the SecurityContext modified as I used to do with my session.

So I'm thinking I either need to:

A. restructure my UserObject to get all that other stuff out of there and add them to the session after authentication with a custom filter,

B. create a new authentication object after each change (sounds super expensive....)

C. some other thing that I haven't yet seen or understood...

I've checked many answers and it seems a common problem, but none address my specific concerns/questions.  AM I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't store data in the session. Your client-server relationship should be stateless. If you have to, as in Spring Security, keep your UserDetails object as light as possible.

Comment: Stateless *except* for security credentials. The client should not have to pass the security credentials for each request to the server (at least in many cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. The intent of a UserDetails object is for it to be immutable. It's supposed to be loaded by a UserDetailsService as part of an authentication process.

I would vote for A: restructure your user object and put as little in the session as possible. Really the user object should only be storing the authorities relevant to your application, and *possibly* user attributes that don't change very much (name, title, etc.) and only if the application needs them for display or processing purposes. It should *not* be storing data you're accumulating as the user uses the application (tracking habits, clicks, etc.). That should be stored elsewhere, such as in a database.

Comment: Jonathan I appreciate the response, but how can I both take this stuff out of the UserDetails object and also not have it in the session?  If I'm getting this stuff from the db new every time I make a change, that sounds about as expensive as creating a new authentication object to store every change to UserDetails.  It seems very likely that I need to optimize my data strategy altogether.

Comment: What's the nature of the data that's changing? Is this per-user data that you're changing, or is this data that's application wide and better served by a caching strategy?

Comment: Also keep in mind that session data is stateful data, so if you're working in a clustered environment, every single change you make to the session object has to have the ability to be able to fail over to any other member of the cluster... which usually means a database write regardless. Multiply the need to be able to do this by the number of users on your system whose sessions haven't timed out or explicitly invalidated the session, and  you could probably guess why any kind of significant data in session can cause scalability problems.

Comment: The data is a tree with an infinite number nodes and branches. 

Currently the User can close/open branches, drag/drop nodes/branches to other nodes/branches, edit nodes in place, etc... and so the tree is definitely "stateful." ajax handles these events for the underlying obj/db.

I knew eventually I needed to both lazily load the tree and limit the number of nodes returned.

I didn't count on needing to split up the user objects into immutable and mutable (user & tree seem logical) components.  Ha even as I write this I see the answer, I guess I've just been wedded to my current approach.